# Relativistic Doppler Effect and the Sagnac effect

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, interferometry

What I think I know about the Sagnac effect can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect).

It occurs to me that the equations for calculating the time do not take the Doppler effect into account. 
I'm familiar with the very basics of the relativistic Doppler effect, and that only the relative velocities between the emitter and detector (which in the case of the Sagnac effect is zero)matter, but shouldn't it be more complex?

More Specifically:

Why is it not the relative velocity of the receiver with respect to the photon itself?

How would one account for this in the Sagnac effect equations, if it does make a difference?

Comment: *Why is it not the relative velocity of the receiver with respect to the photon itself?* The velocity of light relative to anything is always the same. It's just $c$.

Comment: Right, that was poorly worded. I understand if I were moving toward the source, and thus toward the photon I would experience a blue shift, in order to keep light moving at the same speed relative to me. Perhaps I should have asked a different question. If  there were an emitter one light year away from the observer, and that emitter disappeared, the photons emitted beforehand would still be moving toward the observer. If the observer then moved toward the photons they would experience a blue shift yes?

Comment: also in the case of using fiber optics for the loops, you need to consider that light itself is not travelling at $c$ but at $nc$ with $n$ being refraction index in the local rest frame of the fiber.

Comment: Note that because of the subtraction the index effect term disappears, see; .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect  ,  ''  Remarkably, the time difference is independent of the refraction index {\displaystyle n}n and the velocity of light in the fiber.''.

Comment: The Sagnac effect has been shown to be independent of the fiber index and also of the enclosed area. The time shift is proportional to the product of velocity of the source/receiver combo and the distance between them and the result is obtained using the Lorentz transformation. This suggests that the Sagnac effect is a kind of a doppler phenomenon- same link above.